# Azure Active Directory password reset

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, passwords

As an account owner and global admin I am trying to reset the password of an AD user via the AD interface. I am seeing the following error:

[AD user reset password error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOFCs.png)

We recently created an AADDS instance which most users have joined - it seems as though these users are the ones that we are seeing issues resetting. I have checked audit lots and don't see anything obvious.

Not exactly sure what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

"We're sorry, we're not able to reset this user's password right now. This may be due to temporary issues on our end. Please wait a few minutes and try again".

It is possible that this issue is related to Azure, but if these are hybrid users with Azure AD Connect set up, more often this error is related to Azure AD Connect health. I recommend confirming that the Microsoft Azure AD Sync service is running and checking the logs on the sync server.